# AngularJS object transformation or filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a resource in AngularJS returning an object that looks something like this:

```
[
 {
  field: {
   name: 'foo'
  },
  field_value: 'bar'
 },
 {
  field: {
   name: 'foo2'
  },
  field_value: 'bar2'
 } 
]
```

Each field name will be unique, and I want to be able to pull out values by name to populate a form.  Something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{data.foo}}" />  # this should equal 'bar'
```

How can I filter that object to easily access the values?  Or should I perform a transformation on the data first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, transforming the data into a proper form is best. I recommend performing the data manipulation in the resource that returns it, before the return.

```
var newData = {};

data.forEach(function (item) {
        newData[item.field.name] = item.field_value;
    }
);

console.log(newData.foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform the data info a form, which serves your GUI. You'll avoid a lot of troubles.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newb.  Do you mean that I should do a transformResponse as it's coming out of the service rather than trying to build my form around the wonky response?

Comment: No obviously your JSON structure doesn't serve your GUI very well. Best is to put in another form.

Comment: That doesn't really help me.  I don't have control over the JSON response.